# Are slugs still required?

Tags: php, html, web

I always used to transform major information of an entity (e.g. title, name) with a ***slugifizer*** to a slug which doesn't contain spaces, special chars etc.

Now I accidentally forgot the ***slugifizer*** and it worked too even with spaces.

Is a slug still required in this time?

Except for IE users of course...

Regards

PS:
I don't want to start a discussion about this topic. I just want to know if all modern browsers (and backends of course) can handle all problems a **not-slugged value** could cause.

Comment: Type something like "localhost/example page.html" in your browser; you will see it becomes "localhost/example%20page.html". It kills readability and user friendliness. Don't do it.

Comment: You just made that word up, didn't you.

Comment: Nowhere in your question you mention URLs. You do mean slugs in URLs, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slugs were primarily for SEO value.

URLs cannot contain spaces or other reserved characters.  If you put spaces in your URL and it works, it's because the browser is being nice to you, not because it is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with slugs being primarily for SEO. Yes, they *were* (and *are*) used for SEO, but other advantages (which, IMO, are more important than SEO) include users being able to recognize a page without additional information (e.g. `/html-is-awesome/` compared to `/?id=145`), pasting into forums without BBCode or equivalent and having it parsed correctly (e.g. `.../html-is-awesome/` compared to `.../HTML is awesome/`), users being able to type it easily, and portability between content management systems (a new CMS may display a different page for `/?id=145`).

Answer (score 0):

It's nasty when you try to copy / paste URLs around. Try to send an URL that is not sanitized to someone on any messenger, for example. It will most likely break the formatting and the recipient can't click it properly. Also, many email service providers tend to parse URLs to add hyperlinks on them, and this can make the email recipients receive a malformed URL...